# Cefsharp: Get hyperlinks from document

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, cefsharp

I am used to getting hyperlinks in a document like this:

```
    Dim html As String =
                                    "var linksArray = new Array(); " &
                                    "for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {" &
                                    "linksArray[i] = [String(document.links[i].innerHTML), String(document.links[i].innerText), String(document.links[i].href)];" &
                                    "} " &
                                    "return linksArray;"

    Try
        Dim linksArray As JSArray = _Browser.WebView.EvalScript(String.Format("(function(){{ {0} }})()", html))

        For Each obj As Object In linksArray

            Dim sInnerHTML As String = obj(0).ToString().Trim()
            Dim sInnerText As String = obj(1).ToString().Trim()
            Dim sHRef As String = obj(2).ToString().Trim()

            Dim nItem As New clsURL
            nItem.HRef = sHRef
            nItem.InnerHTML = sInnerHTML
            nItem.InnerText = sInnerText

            nList.Add(nItem)

        Next
```

However, CefSharp does not have JSArray.

Can anybody tell me what would be the way to do that with CefSharp?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Have a read over the `FAQ`, particularly https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#2-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-that-return-a-result

`EvaluateScriptAsync` will return a `List<object>` (in yours case each entry will likely be another `List<object` as you've got nested arrays)

I've created a `Gist` as an example, it's in `C#`, you should be able to port it to `VB.Net` (I cannot help you there)

https://gist.github.com/amaitland/9d354376960b0cd9305a
(I plan to add a slightly more detailed example to the `FAQ`, so yours case seems like a reasonable candidate).

As a side note, when executing blocks of code using `EvaluateScriptAsync` I recommend using an anonymous closure.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it can be made synchronous?

Comment: For what reason? I'd advise against using sync code in regards to any `UI` operation.

Comment: EO.Brower can do that reliablly, so I thought it would be possible with CefSharp as well.

Comment: Anything stopping you from spawning a `Task` to execute your calls, then await on the result. Then perform a `BeginInvoke` to update your `UI`? Without a firm grasp on the threading model used by `CEF` I'd advise against trying to make anything `sync`.